# Inject unique mongoose instance in module

Tags: node.js, dependency-injection, mongoose

My modules get a mongoose instance injected but now they all use the database that was set on the last mongoose.

For example my main module creates a lot of modules and then calls init on them.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
//...
mongoose.connect(connString);//specific to finance
var finance = require('finance').init({db:mongoose});
```

Before I injected the mongoose instance the finance module required mongoose by itself and since it's in the node_modules it gets it's own mongoose. Now; no matter how many main modules I make and how many times I call require it'll always get the instance it got the first time.

Therefor all modules created will be connected to whatever is set by the last connect.

It is possible to use createConnection but still not sure how to inject mongoose, I tried:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
//...
var c = mongoose.createConnection(connString);//specific to finance
mongoose.connection=c;
var finance = require('finance').init({db:mongoose});
```

Now I get an error `like Cannot overwrite`finance`model once compiled.`

Somehow it's very hard to get another instance of mongoose in the same module. This is funny because according to mongoose you should be able to use different connections for different models but since you need a mongoose instance to define a model then how do you inject it? Require keeps returning the same instance over and over again.

Tried the following but both didn't work.

```
console.log('deleting mongoose cache:',require.cache.mongoose=undefined);
//or this one
console.log('deleting mongoose cache:',delete require.cache.mongoose);
```

So the question is: how do I inject mongoose in my modules that have models that require a unique database? If main sets up the mongoose instance and connection to inject into the model then how do I prevent it from creating the same one over and over again?

If it's possible to create unique connections with createConnection then what do I inject into the modules? With this connection I can't create models, need a mongoose instance for that. If each model needs to invoke require to get it then mongoose is un injectable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So mongoose uses a singleton pattern. When you do `require("mongoose")` you are getting the same instance of a constructor each time as seen at the bottom of `mongoose/lib/index.js` ([source code link here](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/blob/51f8ccb1a27a8cedeeaf41bbe0c91cd1a117df28/lib/index.js#L649)). `var mongoose = module.exports = exports = new Mongoose;`

To get unique instances, use this pattern:

```
var singleton = require("mongoose")
var unique = new singleton.constructor();
//now use "unique" just as you would "mongoose"
```

Comment: Thank you Peter, I see that mongoose exposes the constructor as Mongoose: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-Mongoose I will try this. The constructor is something JavaScript gives you on the function.prototype but can be re set.